# Python - MySQL hangs in between

Tags: python, mysql

I've an endpoint which inserts the data into the DB table. Following is my code:-

```
@app.route('/user',methods=['POST'])
def user():
    data = request.form
    loginfo= {
               'user_id' : data['user_id'],
               'dob' : data['dob'],
               'gender' : data['gender'],
               'imei1' : data['imei1'],
               'epoch' : data['epoch'],
              }

    if CONNECTION is None:
        return '{"status":503,"error":"MySQL not connected. Service Unavailable."}'

    try:
        create_user_profile(loginfo)
    except Exception,e:
        return '{"status":500,"error":' + str(e) + '}'        

    return '{"status":200}'
```

In my access logs, I get the following logs.

```
[pid: 17877|app: 0|req: 1/1] 127.0.0.1 () {36 vars in 494 bytes} [Thu May 21 05:49:22 2015] POST /user => generated 14 bytes in 11 msecs (HTTP/1.0 200) 2 headers in 79 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
```

Though it is returning `200`(because I've applied try except), it still does not inserts a record into the table. Wherever I reload uwsgi via `uwsgi --reload /var/run/uwsgi.pid` it starts working fine. I'm assuming upon reloading the uwsgi breaks the MySQL connection, re-make it and then it start again, hence works fine.

How do I debugg it?? this error has came multiple times. I keep reloading it.

PS : Since I've applied try-except hence I was not able to view the errors. It was deployed on production. I've now wriiten the print statements. Will let you guys know when it comes next.

In my another project, same error occurs but it returns 500, since I've not applied try-except in that.

**UPDATE**

Following is my code. Please note that some variables has been trimmed off for easiness. If you find any syntax error, please ignore them. Rest the logic remains the same.

```
def data_exist(self,data_exist_query):
    with self.connection:
        cur = self.connection.cursor()
        cur.execute(data_exist_query)
        rows = cur.fetchall()
        if len(rows) >= 1 :
            return True
        else :
            return False


def create_table_index_query(self,tc_query,in_query=None,ix_query=None,show_index_query=None):
    with self.connection:
        cur = self.connection.cursor()
        cur.execute(tc_query)
        cur.execute(in_query)
        self.connection.commit()

        if ix_query:
            cur = self.connection.cursor()
            cur.execute(show_index_query)
            rows = cur.fetchall()
            if len(rows) < 3 :
                print 'Creating Index'
                cur.execute(ix_query)
                self.connection.commit()


def create_user_profile(self, dct):
    rows = (str(dct['user_id']),str(datetime.strptime(dct['dob'],'%d-%m-%Y')), str(dct["gender"]), str(dct["imei1"]),str(dct['epoch']))
    found = False
    data_exist_query = "SELECT * from USER_PROFILE WHERE imei1 = '%s'" % (dct['imei1'],)
    try:
        found = self.data_exist(data_exist_query)
    except:
        pass

    if not found:
        in_query = "INSERT INTO USER_PROFILE (user_id,dob, gender, imei1,epoch) "\
               "VALUES ('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s') " % rows

        self.create_table_index_query(tc_query,in_query)
```

Comment: Which one SQL library are you using?

Comment: can you share the `create_user_profile ` function?

Comment: @YuriG. I've updated my code. You can find the same.

Comment: Where in create_user_profile do you initialize variable tc_query?

Comment: @avk - I've already said that I've trimmed off the non-important part of my code.

Comment: in general I would wrap every `cur.execute()` with a `try` and `except` blocks and would print the relevant messages. In this way you can trace where the code fails exactly

Comment: Does sql closes the connection if there are no transactions happening?